# se puede pasar una app hecha en ionic a aionic 2??

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Tengo esta gran duda, si se puede pasar una APP que está contruida con ionic 1 y ahora quiero hacer unas modificaciónes, pero ya salio ionic 2, se podra o es mejor hacerla de nuevo con ionic 2 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede migrar... me gustaría decirte que sin problemas, pero te estaría mintiendo.

- Si es una app muy básica te recomiendo reescribirla.
- Si es un poco mas compleja pues deberás migrarla.

Te dejo la documentación oficial, ya que es muy largo el procedimiento como para transcribirlo.

[Migrar Ionic V1 a V2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/migration/)

Saludos